# Password Reset Redirect URL in Cookie

Tags: php, symfony

My password reset process is as follows:

1. User clicks button, sends reset email to the email provided
2. Clicks on password reset link, opens up web page
3. User submits new password
4. Redirect back to where the user was originally (e.g. "view cart page")

I can't use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` because there are multiple redirects in my logic for certain authentication algorithms when resetting the password. Using the HTTP_REFERER would be unreliable (I think).

Would it be a bad idea to store the original URL in a cookie, and then utilize that data in the cookie after the user completes the password reset process? Or should I go a different route, and keep the redirect link as a param in the reset email link, and store it in a hidden field on the reset password form?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: i would send them back to front page or login myself after password reset.

Comment: Any particular reason why? I saw a few things on the internet stating why its a better idea to go back to the login page or home page, but nothing really persuasive. @smith

Comment: its where i would expect to be taken personally, even on an e-commerce site.

Comment: Sending the reset token via email implies a certain amount of time before the user actually resets their password.  Will the user even remember (let alone care) where they were when they requested the reset?  So I'm with smith here.  However, if you are determined to do this then go stateless and add the redirect info to your email reset link.

Answer (score 0):

You could gererate a unique id. Then you are sending a link to the email adress with the unique id in the get paramet f.e.: reset_password?id=21948HJK9
To verify that it's the right user, you could store the id in a database and delete it if someone is trying to access it afer 24hrs. When reset_password is opened you search the database for the id and verify it. In the database th id is connected to the account. If the id in the database and the get parameter match it's verified.

Comment: i think he has that part done, question is about returning the user to the previous location

Comment: Then he could just add this to the database into the same column with the id and the user data

Answer (score 0):

From the process you give us, the Step 1 should store the value of the URL somewhere.

Your "Reset password" button could be something like this:

```
<a href="reset_password.php?prev_url=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">Reset password</a>
```

This would give you a variable with the current URL encoded, i.e. the page where the user is located.

Then, the `reset_password.php` file could store the `$_GET['prev_url']` URL in your password reset table (which also stores the reset link).

So, in your last step, when your reset link is validated, simply take the `prev_url` column in your table, store it in a variable (`$prev_url` in my example) and do a:

```
header('location:'.$prev_url);
```